# MySQL server won't start (Mac OSX / MAMP)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, macos, mamp

I'm working locally on a WordPress site. I started on an iMac using XAMPP for mac. A week into working on the site I duplicated it with the duplicator plugin to my macbook pro where I use MAMP. (don't know if this is relevant but I'm really new to this) A few days later, after working I pulled my macbook pro from sleepmode and the MySQL server was down. The localhost:8888 showed "**ERROR CONNECTING TO DATABASE**" and localhost:8888/phpyadmin showed **error #2002**.

I tried using the killall command in terminal which didn't help at all.

```
sudo killall -9 mysqld
```

I tried removing the ibdata files in the db/mysql/ folder. that started up the mySQL server and let me access localhost:8888/phpmyadmin and the WebStart page. But when trying to access the localhost:8888/ to actually access the site nothing works. browsers (safari/firefox/chrome) show too many redirects occurred.

I'm really lost now.

Comment: Does the Apache error log have anything useful?

Comment: Restore from the offending files from a recent backup, sounds like something is very very broken, and it'd be faster to roll back to a working configuration.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch the apache error log doesn't show any errors. I checked out the mySQL error log which is about 2000 lines of warnings.